# Putty pscp Illegal file descriptor format error

Tags: linux, putty, pscp

i am trying to backup my checkpoint using putty pscp with the cmd:

```
pscp -r admin@<ip address>:/var/log/CPbackup/backups/R77/<file_name.tgz> D:\test_location_on_windows
```

I get the error:

`Protocol error: Illegal file descriptor format`

I tried looking around google for this, really couldn't find much.

Also it's worth mentioning if someone has doubts, checkpoint runs on GAIA OS which is just a linux at its core.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working after the following change.

The user I was using has `/etc/cli.sh` set as shell. SCP requires the user to have /bin/bash set as shell.

Then I created a new user for that and make sure you issue

```
"set user <username> shell /bin/bash"
```